# Precompute arbitrary Winning Strategy in Prolog

Tags: search, prolog, game-engine

Lets say we have the Tic-Tac-Toe game at hand. And we want
to precompute a winning strategy in the following way as a tree.
From the winning moves only one is select and stored in the tree.

The many loosing moves the opponent has, all are stored in the
tree, so that we can blindly use the tree to guide us to our
next winning move, which is than again only one in the tree,

```
       /
  o---*- ..
       \     /
        o---*- ..
             \
```

and so on, one, multiple, one, multiple etc.. How would one
do this in Prolog so that computing one such tree can be done
quite quickly for Tic-Tac-Toe game and a given start configuration?

Comment: The tree you describe shows the evolution of all possible games. However, it contains high amount of duplication (state of the game after A-B-C-D is the same than after C-D-A-B). Tic-tac-toe has only 3^9=19k different states, less if we consider symmetries.

Comment: N = 37 is enough, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800312/502187 . Maybe even less?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (adapting from min max):

My choices are white nodes, other player's choices are black nodes.

- Form a solving tree depth-first.
- If the game has ended mark this leaf as `won`, `tie` or `lost`.
- If a  black node is not a leaf and all of its children are marked: "keep" all childnodes, mark the node as the worst cenario from its children (`lost` before `tie` before `won`)
- If a white node has **only one** child **left**: copy the marking.
- If a white node has **one marked** child which is maked as `won`, ignore the left over unmarked child-nodes (no traversing necessary). Mark as `won`.
- If a white node has **two marked** children: keep only the best child, prefer `won` over `tie` over `lost`. If the mark is `won` or there are no unmarked nodes left the 2 above rules hold. Otherwise traverse an unmarked child to repeat this process.
- the marking is only important for the minmax, not for the choice-tree.
- for every childnode store the move to reach it
- form the final tree as nested list (while traversing the tree)

Output would look like this:

```
[[1,
   [2,[4,
         [3,[..],[..]],[5,[3,[..],[..],[..]]]
         ]],
   [3,[4,[5,..],[2,..]]],
   [4,..],
   [5,..]
]]
```

I start and have only one option: using move `1`. Then black has the options `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`, where these are all possible moves for black. If he chooses `2`, I choose `4`. Black now has option `3` and `5`. If he chooses `5`, I choose `3` and so on. Be sure to have enough RAM available ;)

Comment: Can it be done with answer set programming (ASP) ?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse I guess so because graphs are easier to handle (in my oppinion), assuming you want to have a precomputet graph and not a tree

Comment: I am fine with graphs, a tree is a special case of a graph. So who would object to graphs?

Comment: @MostowskiCollapse you might know [this](https://xkcd.com/832/) xkcd comic already?

Comment: N = 37 is enough, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800312/502187 . Maybe even less?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some proof of the pudding. One can use aggregate_all/3 for min/max, here is a little adaptation of the code [here](https://github.com/jburse/jekejeke-samples/blob/master/jekrun/benchmark/tests/tictac.p). But the code below does not yet return a winning strategy. It only returns a first move and a score:

```
% best(+Board, +Player, -Move, -Score)
best(X, P, N, W) :-
  move(X, P, Y, N),
  (win(Y, P) -> W = 1;
    other(P, Q),
    (tie(Y, Q) -> W = 0;
     aggregate_all(max(V), best(Y, Q, _, V), H),
     W is -H)).
```

We can check the moves and scores we get for a position:

```
?- best([[x, -, o], [x, -, -], [o, -, -]], x, N, W).
N = 2,
W = -1 ;
N = 5,
W = 1 ;
N = 6,
W = -1 ;
N = 8,
W = -1 ;
N = 9,
W = -1
```

Now how would we go about and store a winning strategy and choose a winning strategy? One idea here is now to replace the aggregate_all/3 by a findall/3. This should give us the multi branches of a winning strategy:

```
% best(+Board, +Player, -Tree, -Score)
best(X, P, N-R, W) :-
  move(X, P, Y, N),
  (win(Y, P) -> R = [], W = 1;
    other(P, Q),
    (tie(Y, Q) -> R = [], W = 0;
     findall(M-V, best(Y, Q, M, V), L),
     max_value(L, -1, H),
     (Q == x ->
         filter_value(L, H, J),
         random_member(U, J),
         R = [U];
         strip_value(L, R)),
     W is -H)).
```

We use random_member/2 for the single branches. Rerun to get different correct results:

```
?- best([[x, -, o], [x, -, -], [o, -, -]], x, N, W), W = 1.
N = 5-[2-[6-[]], 6-[9-[]], 8-[9-[]], 9-[6-[]]],
W = 1 ;
No

?- best([[x, -, o], [x, -, -], [o, -, -]], x, N, W), W = 1.
N = 5-[2-[8-[6-[9-[]], 9-[6-[]]]], 6-[9-[]], 8-[6-[]], 9-[6-[]]],
W = 1 ;
No
```

Open source:

**Prolog code for the tic-tac-toe game**
score via aggregate, return first move
https://gist.github.com/jburse/928f060331ed7d5307a0d3fcd6d4aae9#file-tictac2-pl

**Prolog code for the tic-tac-toe game**
score via findall, return random winning strategy
https://gist.github.com/jburse/928f060331ed7d5307a0d3fcd6d4aae9#file-tictac3-pl